# How do we pronounce a linux path eg. "/sys/kernel/debug/"?

Tags: linux

What is the correct way to pronounce a Linux path?

For example, if we take "/sys/kernel/debug/", I have always been calling it as "*root-sys-kernel-debug*".

However, I've heard of many different ways people pronounce it:

1. There is an entry in "*slash sys kernel debug*"
2. There is an entry in "*root sys kernel debug*"
3. There is an entry in "*slash sys slash kernel slash debug*"

Is there any standard way?

Comment: Kindly explain your downvote. In my understanding, this question is totally on topic and a perfectly valid question that can be answered in a reasonable time.

Comment: It will depend who you are talking to. Some forms are quicker, but others are clearer.

Comment: You better write it down ;-) If you're talking to someone familiar with linux, you can pronounce it like 'sys kernel debug' debug without any 'slash'. Otherwise, you'll have to spell it out letter by letter, or it may turn into `/ cis / colonel / D-bug`.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't use _root_, since I think that would create confusion with _slash-root_. I'd just say _sys-kernel-debug_, someone who knows enough Linux would of course understand I'm referring to _slash-sys_.